# Equivalence between $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\|x\|=\max_t |x(t)|$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be a Banach space with norm $\| \cdot \|_1$, and when $\|x_n-x\|_1\to 0$, for any $t\in[0,1]$, $|x_n(t)-x(t)|\to 0$ holds. Prove that, $\| \cdot \|_1$ is equivalent to the norm $\|x\|=\max_t |x(t)|$.

I don't have any ideas about the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the relationship between $C$ and $[0,1]$?

Comment: Sorry I lost something just now. Now it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity map
$$
  \text{id}: (C[0, 1], \|\cdot\|_1) \to  (C[0, 1], \|\cdot\|_\infty )
  $$
is continuous by the Closed Graph Theorem.  Therefore it is a homeomorphism by the Open Mapping Theorem, so the norms
are equivalent.

Comment: You can not use the closed graph thm, since $(X,|| \cdot||_1) $ is not complete

Comment: I suppose the OP is referring to $\|\cdot\|_1$ as some abstract norm, not necessarily the integral norm.   Of course this is not the best choice of notation but that is how I interpret it.

Comment: Ah, you are right, it's a  misleading notation

Comment: Yes, very bad notation. But in fact the completeness is given. (We assume $(C,||\cdot||_1)$ is a Banach space...)

Comment: And completeness [is really necessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16447/norms-on-c0-1-inducing-the-same-topology-as-the-sup-norm).

Answer (score 0):

This can't be true. Consider the identity map
$$ id \colon (X,|| \cdot||_1) \to (X,||\cdot ||_\infty) .$$
Evidently, $id$ has a closed graph but it is not continuous (take $u_n(t)=t^n$, then $||u_n||_1=\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0 $ but $||u_n||_\infty=1$). As a result, $(X,|| \cdot||_1) $ is not a Banach space.

Comment: It isn't the $L_1$ norm used here, but a norm that does give  a Banach space using, perhaps, misleading notation.